# Tomcat and self-signed certificate

Tags: tomcat, ssl, hostname, self-signed

I made my self-signed certificate with `keytool` and adapt my server.xml for using ssl with `keystorePass` and other, ...

If I access to URL via *IP address* I get warning about non-trusted certs, but I can make exception and use site without problem. (just warning in left corner of URL bar)

But, when I access to URL via *HOSTNAME* I get same warning, but I cannot make exception.

**First question**:
Where I made mistake about certificate and server.xml configuration for IP vs Hostname

**Second question**:
How can I make certs pair for only certain users (I will share that part of certificate - public, private or whatever, I do not know :( via GPO ) have access to my web site via hostname or ip address.

**Note**: Yes it is intranet

Comment: There should be no differences if you are accessing HTTPS URL via IP or Hostname. Which browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome and FF. Same on both :/

Answer (score 1):

I would try using `-ext` option of the `keytool` e.g. something like this

```
-ext san=dns:[yourhostname],ip:127.0.0.1,ip:[yourhostip]
```

where you should replace `[yourhostname]` with the actual host name, and `[yourhostip]` with the actual `ip`

Take a look here [keytool options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html), look for `-ext` and `san`.

Comment: As I can see it is problem with my Chromium and FF on my Linux machine. From Konqueror and from Chrome and FF from Windows machine works properly.

Now, I need help with second question/issue :)

Comment: @Kolesar If I understand your 2nd problem correctly - you need to implement `client authentication` on server. create a number of certificates for the users. add those certificates to server's `truststore` and somehow distribute proper certificate to each user... piece of cake ;-)

Comment: But I have a lot of users. I should create separate client cert for each user?

Comment: @Kolesar Ideally - yes. but I think nothing is stopping you from using the same certificate on  different clients...